# How to skip elements in custom vertical slider based on input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to skip some elements with class "skip", based on input value, but it's not working OK when input value "No" is selected.

```
$("input:radio[name='q1']").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
    $('.skip').removeClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $('.skip').addClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

here's the complete code in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darkosss/zLyy35vs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i think this is what you were trying to do:

https://jsfiddle.net/jfojv01e/

the problems were:

1. you were using `.next()` only gives `the immediate sibling` so use `.nextAll` instead

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .next() method allows us to search through the immediately following
>   sibling of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery
>   object from the matching elements

2. Your condition was backwords it should be `$(this).val() == 'No'`
3. You werent skiping the hidden elements so it was still finding them... see the `:not` selector i added `$currentItem.nextAll('.scrollStep:not(.hidden)')`

Comment: @Darko glad to help :P

Answer (score 0):

You're adding `hidden` class, where is this in your CSS? Did you mean to use `$('.skip').hide()` ?